# How to Download from Jupyter Notebook without Extra Comments

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, comments, shebang

Apologies if it has already been asked, or if the solution is trivially simple.

Using Jupyter Notebook for Python scripting. When I download a notebook as a .py file (by clicking on *File->Download as->Python (.py)*), Jupyter adds a bunch of extraneous commented lines. It adds some interpreter shebang, encoding declaration at the beginning, and then `#In[], #Out[]` for each cell etc. To make matters more troublesome, the shebang looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

even though I am using a python3 kernel.

While I am sure it has the best intentions, very often I want to have my own interpreter directive and skip the other commented lines altogether since they do nothing but adding to the clutter.

How to download just the raw codes, only with comments that *I* inserted, and cells separated by nothing but line breaks? Also, I would like to know a permanent solution to change the configuration to download it this way, for all ipynb files on my machine, not a one time commmand.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python "path/to/notebook.ipynb" \
--TemplateExporter.exclude_markdown=True \
--TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True \
--TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True
```

It will produce a Python file containing only your Python code and without `#In[], #Out[]`

The `\` in the command is just to write the command on multiple lines and can be removed.

### Permanent Configuration

To make this configuration permanent:

1. Create a file named `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` inside the directory `~/.jupyter/`. Create the directory if not existing.
2. Write inside the file:

   ```
   from nbconvert import TemplateExporter
   TemplateExporter.exclude_markdown=True 
   TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True
   TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True
   ```
3. Now you can run the command:

   ```
   jupyter nbconvert --to python "path/to/notebook.ipynb"
   ```

   to get a Python file with code only.

Sources:
[1](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) [2](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html)

Comment: I get the sourcecode by clicking on File->Download as->Python (.py). Does the command you wrote (when run in the terminal of present working directory) download it for me? Or does it set the configuration for future downloads?

Comment: Yes. This command actually downloads your notebook as a Python file with code content only. It doesn't set any permanent configurations.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct if it solves your problem @Della

Comment: Thanks. While this is useful, I am looking for more like a configuration setting to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being pedantic, but again, since the command includes a path-to-notebook, is the solution only for a specific notebook or all notebooks on the PC? Also, do I have to convert with that command each time, or can I use my old method via the GUI? Finally, I tried it and it is not working completely. It is removing the input output prompt, but not the shebang and encoding declaration at the top. Also, the shebang is wrong.

Comment: Can you also configure that "raw" cells are always commented or left away in the python file? Currently raw cells are just used as real code if downloading the notebook to a .py.

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but you can directly change the `python.tpl` file which refers to the template Jupyter Notebook uses when creating your python file.

1. Find your `python.tpl` file. Mine is located at: `C:\Anaconda3\envs\<my_env_name>\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\templates`, where the `<my_env_name>` is just the name of an environment I created. I just did a windows search on `'nbconvert\templates'` to find the directory.
2. Back up the original `python.tpl` file by copying and pasting it somewhere. I just made an `original_templates` folder in the same directory above.
3. Edit the `python.tpl` file (not the one you copied for backup) with your desired changes to the template.
   If you just want the code blocks without the headers / comments, below is the basic structure I used:

> ```
> {%- extends 'null.tpl' -%} 
> {% block input %} 
> {{ cell.source | ipython2python }} 
> {% endblock input %}
> ```

4. Save changes.

Now all future downloads as a python file in this environment should just be the code without the extra comments.

For more details on customizing the template, try referring to the nbconvert docs: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html

**Note**: I edited the template file in the environment, so if I switch environments within anaconda I would also need to make the sames changes to the template file in the other environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a fix, but you know how it is, sometimes you just gotta get the job done.

I downloaded my notebook with

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python my/path/notebook.ipynb
```

Then, I just opened it with Sublime Text.

After that, just needed to get rid of all the cell references e.g. : '# In[22]:' in the script.  Using find and replace in Sublime Text you can select RegEx, and this:

```
(# In\W[0-9]+\W:)+
```

Will solve that.